# Using Timeout to avoid deadlock in Java multithreading

Tags: java, multithreading, locking, timeout, deadlock

One of the strategy to avoid deadlock situation in Java Multithreading is using timeout.
Suppose, one thread has acquired lock on one resource and now waiting for lock on another resource. After certain time period if it can not acquire lock on resource2 then it should stop waiting for lock on resource2. Also it should release lock on resource1. Thus deadlocks will be avoided.

But how to implement it in Java ? How to explicitly "release" lock ? How to define timeout to wait for lock.

What is exact java commands and syntax. Any hello-worldish example please ?

Comment: Other solutions; always acquire locks in the same order, or never acquire more than one lock. ;)

Comment: +1 for `How to define timeout to wait for lock`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is a contrived example with 2 locks and 2 threads that try to acquire them in different orders. Without the timeout, the code would deadlock.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    final ReentrantLock lock1 = new ReentrantLock();
    final ReentrantLock lock2 = new ReentrantLock();
    Runnable try1_2 = getRunnable(lock1, "lock 1", lock2, "lock 2");
    Runnable try2_1 = getRunnable(lock2, "lock 2", lock1, "lock 1");
    new Thread(try1_2).start();
    new Thread(try2_1).start();
}

private static Runnable getRunnable(final ReentrantLock lock1, final String lock1Name, final ReentrantLock lock2, final String lock2Name) {
    return new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                if (lock1.tryLock(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)) {
                    System.out.println(lock1Name + " acquired in thread " + Thread.currentThread());
                    if (lock2.tryLock(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)) {
                        System.out.println(lock2Name + " acquired in thread " + Thread.currentThread());
                        Thread.sleep(2000);
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("Could not acquire "+lock2Name + " in thread " + Thread.currentThread());
                        lock1.unlock();
                        System.out.println(lock1Name + " released in thread " + Thread.currentThread());
                    }
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Could not acquire " + lock1Name + " in thread " + Thread.currentThread());
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                //you should not ignore it
            } finally {
                if (lock1.isHeldByCurrentThread()) lock1.unlock();
                if (lock2.isHeldByCurrentThread()) lock2.unlock();
            }
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: example from Java Concurrency In Practice!! ;)

Comment: @assylias When calling a synchronized method of an object, thread automatically tries to get "lock on that object" . Whereas while using "java.util.concurrent.locks.Lock" we will not not request "lock on object that object" whose method we are calling. So I think that, to correctly use "Lock" class we should NOT mark method as synchronized. But we should have an instance of "Lock" associted with that object. And before calling the code-which needs synchronization- we should go for tryLock() on related lock.    ---- Plz continue reading below comment  ------

Comment: @assylias
So we are not physically locking the object whose method we are calling, but logically locking. 
Like we have a balckboard for each object and before calling method we just write on blackbord that "Hey, I have got the lock !!" . We do not actually lock object. 
Other thread will check the blackboard and see that some one has "said" that he has lock. So it will not continue. 

Am I right ?

Comment: @NarendraPathai Possibly - I did not take it from there to be honest.

Comment: @assylias I didn't mean you copied it. :) Just remembered it was given in it! Cheers! Good example!

Comment: @KaushikLele in the end a lock (whether it is an explicit lock or a synchronized method) is there (among other things) to prevent two threads from executing the same code block simultaneously. So you can use one or the other but there is no need to use both (and you reintroduce a deadlock risk if you do).

Answer (score 4):

may this help,

```
Lock lock = null;
lock=....;
if (lock.tryLock(15L, TimeUnit.SECONDS)) {
    try {
       ........
    } finally {
        lock.unlock();
    }
} else {
      // do sumthing
}
```

Answer (score 3):

[Lock in Java](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Lock.html)

```
Use tryLock(timeout, timeunits);
```

> Acquires the lock if it is **free** within the given **waiting time** and the
>   current thread has not been interrupted. If the lock is available this
>   method returns **immediately** with the value `true`.
>
> If the lock is not
>   available then the current thread becomes **disabled** for thread
>   scheduling purposes and lies dormant until one of three things
>   happens:
>
> The lock is **acquired** by the current thread;
>
> or Some other thread
>   **interrupts** the current thread, and interruption of lock acquisition is
>   supported;
>
> or The specified **waiting time elapses**

Answer (score 3):

In the [Java 8+ Concurrency API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Condition.html) you can set an explicit time for a `lock` to wait when it's condition is set:

```
private Lock lock = new ReentrantLock();
private Condition myCondition = lock.newCondition();

try{            
    myCondition.await(1200L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    System.out.println((e);
} finally{
    lock.unlock();
}
```

The lock will wait until it receives a `signal()` or `signalAll()` from another thread or until the time of 1.2 seconds expires.