# Possible to acquire a semaphore for a set timeout, then release it, with one line of code?

Tags: java, semaphore

Is there a way to acquire a `Semaphore` for a short interval and then release it after that interval, with just one line of code?  Looking through the semaphore documentation http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html I'm not seeing just that but I'm not familiar with all the terminology.

Alternatively, is there another way to acquire a semaphore while a `TimerTask` is running, then release it automatically?

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13741479/using-timeout-to-avoid-deadlock-in-java-multithreading

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could use the try-with-resources variant: `try (Foo foo = new Foo();) { ... }` with the constructor of the object `Foo()` acquiring the semaphore, and the `foo.close()` method releasing it.